# Convert string to date with format (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, string, date

I have a string with a date in this format. "24-11-2015" or "dd-MM-yyyy". I need to convert this to a date with this format. "2015-11-24" or "yyyy-MM-dd".
I've tried several ways, and all of them rely on my system format for this to work. If i run my program on a computer with english time format this works.

```
Date.ParseExact("24-11-2015", "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

But if i run it on a computer running danish format i get error because there is no 24th month. How do i make the date format independent of my system time format.

Comment: DateTime variables have no formats. It is their representation as strings that give them 'a format'. It is not clear from your question if you have a string representing a date and you want to parse it into a DateTime variable or if you have a DateTime variable  and want it to be shown in a particular way

Comment: Also if this is a desktop app, TryParse can be used to test all possible formats used by the current culture...and some cultures have over 100.

Comment: If the user can enter the complete string directly you are in trouble. The system can't tell the difference between the m-d-yyyy and d-m-yyyy reliably. You need to use separate fields or a date picker.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
Dim dateTime As String = "24-11-2015"
Dim dt As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime)
Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}-{2}", dt.Year, dt.Month.ToString("D2"), dt.Day.ToString("D2"))
```

Solution 2:

```
Dim dateTime As String = "24-11-2015"
Dim dt As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime)
Dim format As String = "yyyy-MM-dd"
Dim str As String = dt.ToString(format)
Console.WriteLine(str)
```

You can also try [Formatting Date and Time for a Specific Culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx).